# HTML version of allure reports

Tags: allure

any way to get an emailable HTML allure reports which I can send after my Jenkins execution. I need this and I am too far with allure to go with another reporting option

Answer (score 3):

Allure report is not a static report. The workaround is to use 'allure generate ' command to save the website files into a specific folder (files include .json files and index.html), store it in AWS S3 bucket and enable web hosting. Then you can send a link of the report to a customer.

More details about this feature request:
https://github.com/allure-framework/allure2/issues/755

Answer (score 2):

After you used 'allure generate' tool you'll get a folder with index.html and other files that are required to view the report.

With my tool you can combine all this files into a single html file that is working fine and have all the other files embedded.
It's in alpha version but already helped me in the same situation https://github.com/MihanEntalpo/allure-single-html-file

Answer (score 0):

```
npx allure generate ./test-results/allure-results --clean --single-file
```

This command will help you to generate a single html file allure report